# text element arcpy, replace text using parameter

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I would like to create a geoprocessing tool to replace text in Layout view. I have the following code which works fine from within Arcgis Python. However, I need users to input Text, i.e all replacement value should be parameter.

e.g

```
if ele.text == "Text1":
    ele.text = "Parameter set by user"
```

Here is the code which I got from the net:

```
import arcpy  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")    
eleList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT")  
for ele in eleList:  
     if ele.text == "Text1":  
         ele.text = "   Vuci"  
     if ele.text == "Text2":  
         ele.text = "co100-xxxx"  
     if ele.text == "Text3":  
         ele.text = "Viti"  
     if ele.text == "Text5":  
         ele.text = "Tai"  

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()  

print "Script completed"
```

[image]

Comment: please format you questions properly for readability.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe I'm comming from the review section. There's an edit pending, probably formatting everything. And it's his first post, it's hard to get it all at once. :)

Wellcome, Ravi!

Comment: True, true. Me too. Actually wanted to edit after reviewing, but can't. Welcome Ravi, indeed!

Comment: Just in case you are not aware of it there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcPy questions already answered on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add user-defined parameters, you should use the [arcpy.GetParameterAsText()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/GetParameterAsText/03q300000090000000/) function in your code and define parameters in the interface of your script tool. See [Setting script tool parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00150000000n000000) for a detailed explanation.